# Interfacing MQ-3 Alcohol Sensor with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, detection, raspberry-pi3

Since MQ-3 sensor provides analog output, we have got MCP 3008. We tried to make the connections with Raspberry pi 3 using the connections from MQ-2 sensor available online. Nothing works! Need help to interface MQ 3 with Raspberry pi 3 for detecting Alcohol Level

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: Output of our code :
LPG: 0.00637006 ppm, CO: 0.00384715 ppm, Smoke: 0.0167834 ppm

Need to calibrate it for sensing alcohol

Answer (score 2):

this link is best to interface analog sensor with raspberry pi 
https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/configure-and-read-out-the-raspberry-pi-gas-sensor-mq-x/
use this link but if you want use analog sensor with raspberry pi so you need another ADC module or another chip like PIC , ATMEGA 32